# Laravel 5.5 Route groups

Tags: laravel-5

I was having this in my website using Laravel 5.3 :

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware'=>'auth'], function(){
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
});
```

This lets me go to the admin panel using: `mywebsite/public/admin/posts`.

Now, when I migrated the site to Laravel5.5 I got this error `Route[admin.posts.create] not defined` when i attempt to open the link `<a href="route('admin.posts.create')">Create post</a>` which was working fine before.

I know that routing system has changed but I did not know how to have such links in new Laravel5.5. I tried `url` instead of `route` but I got the same error. I also checked the new  [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing) but I did not get exactly how to have the same link system.

Can anyone have a better explanation of this new routing system? (I have to migrate the site to 5.5).

Answer (score 0):

Laravel names resource routes by default, you can check them by running `php artisan route:list`

If you want to override them for any reason you can pass in an array when you define the route and override each individual route name like so:

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController', ['names' => [
    'create' => 'admin.posts.build'
]]);
```